# Count valgrind errors without reporting them

Tags: c, valgrind

I am currently maintaining a memory pool. I have recently added valgrind function calls to this pool so as to make it more useful for detecting valgrind errors occurring via the use of said pool. What I want to do with this is to write a unit test to check that my calls to valgrind functions are working properly. E.g.,

```
int main(void)
{
  int * test = pool_malloc(sizeof(*test)); // details not important
  *test = 3;
  pool_free(test); // details not important

  if (*test == 2)
  {
    printf("HERE");
  }

  assert(VALGRIND_COUNT_ERRORS == 1);
}
```

This code now correctly gives me an invalid read error, whereas previously it wouldn't as even though the memory was returned to the pool, it wasn't actually `free`-d. However, I can't use this exact code as our unit test framework assumes that any valgrind errors means the test failed, and therefore my above test would fail. I've tried using `VALGRIND_DISABLE_ERROR_REPORTING`, but that also appears to disable not just reporting, but also checking for errors - i.e., `VALGRIND_COUNT_ERRORS` now returns 0. What I really want is something like `VALGRIND_DISABLE_ERROR_REPORTING_BUT_KEEP_COUNTING_ERRORS_THAT_OCCUR` - does something like that exist? Is there a better way to accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to use the valgrind client request VALGRIND_COUNT_ERRORS.

valgrind.h among others says:

```
    ...
             /* Can be useful in regression testing suites -- eg. can
                 send Valgrind's output to /dev/null and still count
                 errors. */
              VG_USERREQ__COUNT_ERRORS = 0x1201,
    ...
    /* Counts the number of errors that have been recorded by a tool.  Nb:
       the tool must record the errors with VG_(maybe_record_error)() or
       VG_(unique_error)() for them to be counted. */
```

So, something like:
   valgrind --log-file=/dev/null your_program
will make the valgrind errors reported to /dev/null, and your_program can then
output an error if the error count is not as expected.